# Listbox DataTemplate clear textbox value on selection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

For my `ListBox` I have a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="lbTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Naam, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox TextAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
            Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToAlignment}}"
            Text="{Binding Path=Aantal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue=0}"
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Which the properties are bound to:

```
public class menuItem
{
    public int? Aantal { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
}
```

How can I clear the `TextBox` value if the corresponding `ListBoxItem` is selected without losing my binding to the `Aantal?` property?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense... *How can I clear the `TextBox` value if the corresponding `ListBoxItem` is selected without losing my binding to the `Aantal` property?* If the `TextBox` is data bound to the `Aantal` property, then the `TextBox` will display its value and nothing else.

Comment: just use Style and DataTrigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Style` with `DataTrigger`:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="tbStyle">
    <Setter Property="Text" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="Aantal" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                            Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**EDIT**

To reset (clear) the bound `Aantal` property after selection of `ListBoxItem`:

Add `IsSelected` flag to your item class, bind it to `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` property by adding the following style to your `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then in `IsSelected` setter, add code: `if (value) { this.Aantal = ""; }`

Comment: This works, but now my property doesn't get changed when I enter a new value and deselect my `ListBoxItem`?..

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Which property? You want your `Aantal` property to be set to `null` (or `String.Empty`) when you deselect `ListBoxItem`?

Comment: No, **when selected set `Aantal = null`**, User types a new value in the textbox, **`Aantal` becomes the value typed in the textbox**

Comment: Ok so you just want to reset (clear) the `Aantal` property when item is selected, right?

Comment: Correct, it's more of a UI thingy but it's the requirment so.. So set `Aantal` to null, AND make the textbox's text empty

Comment: I still can't get it to work.. Note that i'm just getting to know the power of WPF..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54550/discussion-between-amnezjak-and-demama).